# Getting "ErrImageNeverPull" in pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, dockerhub

Am using `minikube` to test out the deployment and was going through [this](https://itnext.io/running-asp-net-core-on-minikube-ad69472c4c95?gi=c0651899e562) link

And my manifest file for deployment is like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        imagePullPolicy: Never # <-- here we go!
        image: sams
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and after this when I tried to execute the below commands got output

```
user@usesr:~/Downloads$ kubectl create -f mydeployment.yaml --validate=false

deployment "webapp" created

user@user:~/Downloads$ kubectl get deployments

NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
----     --------   -------   ----------   ---------   ----              
webapp    1         1         1            0           9s

user@user:~/Downloads$ kubectl get pods

NAME                     READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
----     --------   -------   ----------   ---------   ----              
webapp-5bf5bd94d-2xgs8   0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          21s
```

I tried to pull images even from `Docker-Hub` by removing line `imagePullPolicy: Never`  from the `deployment.yml` But getting the same error.
Can anyone help me here to identify where and what's going wrong?

### Updated the question as per the comment

```
kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME
Name:           webapp-5bf5bd94d-2xgs8
Namespace:      default
Node:           minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:     Fri, 31 May 2019 14:25:41 +0530
Labels:         app=webapp
            pod-template-hash=5bf5bd94d
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             172.17.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/webapp-5bf5bd94d
Containers:
  webapp:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          sams
    Image ID:       
    Port:           80/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImageNeverPull
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wf82w (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-wf82w:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wf82w
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                From               Message
  ----     ------             ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled          18m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/webapp-5bf5bd94d-2xgs8 to minikube
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull  8m (x50 over 18m)  kubelet, minikube  Container image "sams" is not present with pull policy of Never
  Warning  Failed             3m (x73 over 18m)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImageNeverPull    

docker images:

REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
----------                             ---                 --------            -------             ----
<none>                                 <none>              723ce2b3d962        3 hours ago         1.91GB
bean_ben501/sams                       latest              c7c4a04713f4        4 hours ago         278MB
sams                                   latest              c7c4a04713f4        4 hours ago         278MB
sams                                   v1                  c7c4a04713f4        4 hours ago         278MB
<none>                                 <none>              b222da630bc3        4 hours ago         1.91GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk      2.2-stretch         e4747ec2aaff        9 days ago          1.74GB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet   2.2-stretch-slim    f6d51449c477        9 days ago          260MB
```

---

Comment: Hi, can you run `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME`

Comment: updated it in question @SureshVishnoi

Comment: `Container image "sams" is not present`  can you check if the docker image is there ?

Comment: Its there. Updated the question

Comment: hopefully these images are present on the minikube node

Comment: What steps do you take to get that image into the minikube VM?

Comment: `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command will use minikube docker environment. then build your container

Comment: so what's the status of it now ?

Comment: Yes i did that already

Comment: so these images are on the minikube nodes ? as with the pull policy of `Never` , images need to be on node

Comment: Got it... After `eval $(minikube docker-env)` this i forgot to build the image again. now its up

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> When using a single VM for Kubernetes, it’s useful to reuse Minikube’s built-in Docker daemon. Reusing the built-in daemon means you don’t have to build a Docker registry on your host machine and push the image into it. Instead, you can build inside the same Docker daemon as Minikube, which speeds up local experiments.

The following command does the magic
`eval $(minikube docker-env)`
**Then you have to rebuild your image again.**

for `imagePullPolicy: Never` the images need to be on the minikube node.

[This answer provide details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310599/what-does-minikube-docker-env-mean)

[local-images-in minikube docker environment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#use-local-images-by-re-using-the-docker-daemon)

Comment: after you run minikube docker-env you should run also: @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue and resolved it by running eval $(minikube docker-env). However, it's important to note that before setting the Minikube Docker environment, you should clear the Docker images, deployments, and services if any pods are in the 'ErrImageNeverPull' state

Answer (score 26):

You need to use `eval $(minikube docker-env)` in your current terminal window. This will use the minikube docker-env for the current session.

The image needs to be on the minikube virtual machine. So now you need to build your image again.

**But be careful !** Don't use **sudo** when building the image. It won't use the minikube docker-env.

After you close the terminal, everything will be as it was before.

Then, use `imagePullPolicy: Never` in the manifest file to use the local image registry.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: demo
    image: demo
    imagePullPolicy: Never # <-- here
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
```

Comment: same issue.I'm a windows user can you help?

Comment: Additional upvote for this: `But be careful ! Don't use sudo when building the image. It won't use the minikube docker-env.`

Comment: So - if we don't want add our user to the docker group as it's a security risk, we're s.o.l.? (since we can't run docker without sudo)

Comment: "But be careful ! Don't use sudo when building the image. It won't use the minikube docker-env." This could have saved me 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at this question, but are using `k3s`, instead of the given minikube solution, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590030/access-local-docker-images-with-k3s), or from the [rancher docs](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/#using-docker-as-the-container-runtime). Add a `--docker` flag to the setup for `k3s`.

`curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - --docker`

Answer (score 0):

Check your

```
kubectl version
```

Be sure the client version is up to date with the daemon(Server) version. Read below quote  from the official docs

You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.2 client should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 master. Using the latest version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues.