# deployment in k3s using local image

Tags: docker, nexus3, k3s

I was trying to deploy a nexus app in a k3s cluster, but I'm getting some errors as below:

Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6s (x7 over 81s)         kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "rancher/mirrored-pause:3.6": failed to pull image "rancher/mirrored-pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/rancher/mirrored-pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/rancher/mirrored-pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/rancher/mirrored-pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.12.8.8:53: no such host

Basically, I pull the docker images and imported to k3s, and in the deployment.yaml, also I set the imagePullPolicy to Never, but I'm still getting the same error.

The reason that I was trying to do this is because the cluster has no internet access directly, I have to pass through a proxy. (Also I try to set the proxy in k3s.service and k3s.server.env and nothing changed).

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

The solution was `./k3s server --docker` when start k3s.

[Access local docker images with k3s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590030/access-local-docker-images-with-k3s)