# Airflow KubernetesPodOperator AirflowException('Pod Launching failed: {error}'.format(error=ex))

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, ubuntu-18.04, microk8s

I'm running a KubernetesPodOperator with a custome docker image that was imported with microk8s. When running the DAG in airflow I see the following log until I get the time out message `AirflowException('Pod Launching failed: {error}'.format(error=ex))`

`[2020-04-14 23:06:39,875] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2020-04-14 23:06:39,875[0m] {[34mpod_launcher.py:[0m141} INFO[0m - Event: [1mk8s-pod-ml-3a541375[0m had an event of type [1mPending[0m[0m`

Searching for the problem I ran `microk8s kubectl get pods` on ubuntus terminal and got:
[image]

as you can see the name of the pod is almost exactly the same in the logs (except fro the 1m at the begining) but the status is `ErrImageNeverPull`. I couldn't find anything in the internte regarding that status or the error except for [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) that says '*The default timeout for KubernetesPodOperator is 120 seconds, which can result in timeouts occurring before larger images download.*' I change the default timeout to 600 seconds but did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "ErrImageNeverPull" in pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392041/getting-errimageneverpull-in-pods)

Comment: @mdaniel I saw that before but not because im not running in a VM, i'm not using minikube and `docker-env` is not a subcomand of microk8s

Comment: Just try adding `imagePullPolicy: Never` to your pod spec and let us know if it works.

Comment: @HelloWorld honestly don't know where to add it the config file of a microk8s is different than the one shown in that thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

Microk8s was not having access to docker. I found  out about it by running `microk8s.inspect` and getting the

```
WARNING:  Docker is installed. 
File "/etc/docker/daemon.json" does not exist. 
You should create it and add the following lines: 
{
    "insecure-registries" : ["localhost:32000"] 
}

and then restart docker with: sudo systemctl restart docker
Building the report tarball
  Report tarball is at /var/snap/microk8s/1320/inspection-report-20200415_141500.tar.gz
```

After doing as the warning said airflow manage to deploy the image in the pod.